# Is the sigma algebra generated by $X$ random variable and its square equal to the sigma algebra generated by $X$ alone?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I would like to understand which relationships hold among the sigma algebras $\sigma(X, X^2)$, $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(X^2)$, where X is a random variable. I would expect that $\sigma(X, X^2)=\sigma(X)$. If this is true, then is $X^2$ $\sigma(X)$-measurable?

Moreover, I would like to know if there exist more sigma algebras w.r.t. a process is adapted. I am thinking that if $X_i$ are i.i.d. than $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(S_n)$-measurable but also $\mathcal{G}_n:=\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$-measurable. What changes if I take $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ instead of $\{\mathcal{G}_n\}$ as a filtration for the process $\{S_n\}$? Because for both the process is a martingale!

Comment: "I would expect that $\sigma(X, X^2)=\sigma(X)$." True. "If this is true, then is $X^2$ $\sigma(X)$measurable?" It is. "Because for both the process is a martingale!" No, even for centered i.i.d. $(X_n)$, the process $(S_n)$ is not an $(\mathcal F_n)$-martingale in general, only a $(\mathcal G_n)$-martingale, for example $S_{n-1}$ is not even $\mathcal F_n$-measurable in general.

Comment: Just work it out. For example $X^2\leq y=(X\leq \sqrt{y})\cap (X\geq -\sqrt{y})$ is clearly $\sigma(X)$ measurable for all $y$.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Borel-measurable function and $X$ is a random variable then $Y:=f(X)$ is a random variable measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$. This because for every Borelset $B$ we have: $$\sigma(Y)\ni\{Y\in B\}=\{X\in f^{-1}(B)\}\in\sigma(X)$$You can apply this on function $x\mapsto x^2$ and conclude that $\sigma(X^2)\subseteq\sigma(X)$ and consequently $\sigma(X,X^2)=\sigma(X)$.

Comment: @Did If the $X_i$ are centered, then $S_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable and $\mathbb{E}[S_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=S_{n-1}$ because $X_n$ is indipendent w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ and its expected value is 0, and $S_{n-1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable. Why do you say that $S_n$ is not a $\mathcal{F}_n$ -martingale?

Comment: Because, in general, $S_{n-1}$ is not $\mathcal F_n$-measurable (as already mentioned). The trouble comes from the fact that the sequence $(\mathcal F_n)$ is not (in general) a filtration.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much!